# Limit variable template to a list of types

Tags: c++, templates, gstreamer, unique-ptr

I'm trying to modernise some [GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) code by adding smart pointers. So for instance:

```
GstElement *pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("test-pipeline");
gst_object_unref(pipeline);
```

can be rewritten:

```
struct GstElementDeleter {
    void operator()(GstElement* p) { gst_object_unref(p); }
};

std::unique_ptr<GstElement, GstElementDeleter> pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("test-pipeline");
```

But `gst_object_unref()` can be used on any `gpointer` so it can be rewritten:

```
template<typename T>
struct GPointerDeleter {
    void operator()(T* p) { gst_object_unref(p); }
};

std::unique_ptr<GstElement, GPointerDeleter<GstElement>> pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("test-pipeline");
```

But what I'd like to do is limit this to only handling types that can be deallocated using `gst_object_unref`. Is there a way of declaring a template to only work with a list of types - `GstElement`, `GstBus`, etc?

Comment: You can use std::enable_if

Comment: Shouldn't the subset is only `GstObject*`, so `struct GPointerDeleter {
    void operator()(GstObject* p) const { gst_object_unref(p); }
};`?

Comment: @Jarod42 you'd think that but no - they're not actually defined as GstObject, they have a pointer to GstObject in their struct.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you could make template the `operator()` (so there is no need to explicit the template parameter defining the smart pointer) and use SFINAE to enable the `operator()` only for the allowed types

```
struct GPointerDeleter
 {
    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, GstElement>::value
                         || std::is_same<T, GstBus>::value
                         /* or other cases */
             >::type operator() (T * p) const
     { gst_object_unref(p); }
 };
```

Or, maybe better, you can add (as suggested by Jarod42 (thanks)) a `static_assert()` check inside the `operator()`

```
struct GPointerDeleter
 {
    template <typename T>
    void operator() (T * p) const
     {
       static_assert( std::is_same<T, GstElement>::value
                   || std::is_same<T, GstBus>::value
                   /* or other cases */, "some error message" );

       gst_object_unref(p);
     }
 };
```

Comment: Could be shortende with `std::enable_if_t` and `std::is_same_v`.

Comment: @churill - Yes, if the question would tagged C++17. But the question is tagged only C++. We know that the OP is using at least C++11 (uses `std::unique_ptr`) and, to be sure, I use only C++11 compatible code.

Comment: `static_assert` seems more appropriate than SFINAE here.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Do you mean "there isn't an alternative, so a soft error give the same result as an hard error"? Uhmmm... maybe you're right...

Comment: Notice also that you move template from class to method. (Both are valid though).

Comment: @Jarod42 - Yes: is intended; also to simplify the smart pointer declaration. I've tried to explain it but maybe I'm wrong in English.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a type trait? See [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) if you haven't seen these before.

```
template<typename T>
struct can_gst_unref : std::false_type { };
// for each type...
template<> struct can_gst_unref<GstElement> : std::true_type { };

// convenient alias, as is convention for type traits
template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool can_gst_unref_v = can_gst_unref<T>::value;

// now conditionally define operator() in your deleter
struct GstDeleter {
    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<can_gst_unref_v<T>> operator()(T* p) { gst_object_unref(p); }
};

// Making the function a template instead of the class reduces clutter at usage
std::unique_ptr<GstElement, GstDeleter> works(gst_pipeline_new("test-pipeline"));

// can_gst_unref is not specialized to std::string
// so the general case takes over, and gives can_gst_unref_v<std::string> = false
// std::enable_if_t thus doesn't produce a type, and operator() is not defined, because it has no return type
// therefore, this doesn't compile
std::unique_ptr<std::string, GstDeleter> whoops;
```